# NavigationBar not showing up (View Controller) : Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a ViewController and another second controller called FlavorsController.
My ViewController is my initial view controller. It does not have a navigation controller. I go to the FlavorsController using the following command:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FlavorsController") as! FlavorsController
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I have a NavigationController that is set on FlavorsController however it is not showing up.

[image]

Comment: Create your segue between the two view controllers fist then when while clicked the second VC then click on Editor - Embed In - NavigationController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should present the Navigation Controller instead of the `FlavorsController`, so code should look like this:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NavControllerID") as! NavBarControllerName
    presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

See that `NavControllerID` and `NavBarControllerName` are just names invented by me. Just set the ones you have set in your storyboard.

Comment: did that the first time and it didn't work and when you told me, it did. I feel dumb. Thanks brother. I will accept answer soon.